# Await things but make things run in concurrent manner

Tags: c#, xamarin, async-await

I'm building an android app with xamarin but this question is related mostly to C# .
In my code I need few things to happen, some of them don't need the other parts and can happen in concurrency manner. some of them should wait until previous action to bring results. I'm doing everything I can in an async manner. Currently it seems that I'm always waiting (in an async manner) for things to finish before the next action.

Here is an example of what I'm trying to do:

1. Bring the user image from the phone.
2. Get list of recent phone calls.
3. Get list of specific contacts from phone.
4. Get data from the server about number #2 and #3.

Item **#1** is not connected to anything else. I need it to happen in concurrent with the others. they don't need to wait until it returns. when it ends it should  update the UI.

Item **#2** & **#3** should happen in concurrent. When they **both** end they should update the UI

Item **#4** can only happen when #2 and #3 finish.

My  Question is what do I need in order for this kind of requirement to happen. I only ask for guidelines.

Comment: Start t1, t2 and t3 then `await t2; await t3; t4; await t1;` ? Awaiting a series of things in order will work as expected because awaiting a completed task will return immediately, so you'll always only be "awaiting" the longest task.

Answer (score 4):

The word parallel is mostly used for CPU intensive execution using multiple threads. My guess is that you really mean *concurrent*, which means that the asynchronous operations are executed **simultaneously and not sequentially**.

This is a simple layout of how your `async` methods should interact using `Task.WhenAll` that enables asynchronously waiting for multiple task to complete:

```
async Task Foo()
{
    var t1 = First();
    var t2 = SecondAndThirdAndFourth();

    await Task.WhenAll(t1,t2);   
}

async Task First()
{
    // Bring the user image from the phone.
    // update UI
}

async Task SecondAndThirdAndFourth()
{
    var t2 = Second();
    var t3 = Third();

    await Task.WhenAll(t2, t3);

    // Update UI

    await Fourth();
}
```

If you do mean parallel execution then you need to offload work to a `ThreadPool` thread using `Task.Run`, but that would only parallelize the synchronous parts of the asynchronous methods.

---

<sup>There's no actual reason to store these tasks in a variable, it's just for clarity. In reality I would write `await Task.WhenAll(Second(), Third())` (with proper names)</sup>

Comment: I fixed to "concurrent",you are right (hope I wrote it correctly in the sentence)

Answer (score -1):

I would do something like

```
var t1 = StartTask(t1);

var t4andUIupdateAfterT2andT3 = new List[ CreateAndNotStart(t4) , CreateAndNotStart(UIUpdateAfterT2andT3) ];

var t2andt3 = new List [ StartTask(t1) , StartTask(t1) ];

t1.ContinuteWith(UpdateUI);

t2andt3.Continuewith(t4andUIupdateAfterT2andT3)
```

and you do not await for anything